# Make bootstrap well semi transparent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to make the bootstrap well semi transparent by adding `opacity:0.4` but this results in making the text semitransparent as well. Is there any way to make the well semi transparent without making the body lose opacity as well.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Change the `background-color` instead of changing its `opacity`

```
.well {
   background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.4);
}
```

With a notice that the value `245` comes from the default `background-color` of the `.well` class: `#F5F5F5`.

Comment: In my website using Chrome there's also a background-image being applied by boostrap v3 CSS, which overrules the background-color that I specify, how to fix this?

Answer (score 7):

There's an awesome way of doing this.
You can do it using `rgba` and 'background-color` like this:

```
.well{
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4); // I don't know the .well color, so I used white as example
}
```

where the `0.4` is the opacity and the 255,255,255 the color codes in rgb.

More about rgba:

http://www.css3.info/preview/rgba/

Comment: I figured i cud use the alpha layer but wanted the well to retain the color defined in bootstrap.css

Comment: You could use the rgba on every parent of the well. if you leave the background from the well transparant all the item inside your parent will be with opacity.